# jQRangeSlider set max greater than 100

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using **[jQRangeSlider](http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/index.html)** and try to set the max to a number greater than 100. This does not work as the slider's max remains 100:

```
function initSlider() {
    $("#slider").rangeSlider();
    $("#slider").rangeSlider("min", 0);
    $("#slider").rangeSlider("max", 500);
}
```

Result:

[image]

How do I set the max to be greater than 100?

Or is a max value greater than 100 not supported? I looked on http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/documentation.html but didn't see anything.

Comment: Try `$("#slider").editRangeSlider("max", 500);` As mentioned here http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/methods.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. One needs to use bounds:

To initialize:

```
$("#slider").rangeSlider({ bounds: { min: 0, max: 500 } });
```

To change it later:

```
$("#slider").rangeSlider('bounds', 0, 500);
```

See: http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/methods.html#boundsMethod

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation](http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/methods.html#valuesMethod):

> The method values([min, max]) can be used for getting current selected
>   values, and setting new values.

```
// Edit slider
$("#editSlider").editRangeSlider("values", 20, 100);
```

Comment: changed code to: 
    $("#slider").editRangeSlider("values", 0, 500);  . Still does not work :(

Comment: Is there any error in the console? Can you set up a jsfiddle to work on it?

Comment: Figured it out. See my answer

Comment: I see. It looks that `Values` confused us.

Answer (score 0):

[documentation](http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/methods.html#valuesMethod) states you can set the values in the following way:

```
// Basic slider
$("#slider").rangeSlider("values", 10, 20);
```

so your code would be:

```
function initSlider() {
    $("#slider").rangeSlider("values", 0, 500);
}
```